# Why does 12 X 8.33 seem to equate to about 105?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, tablelayoutpanel

In my TableLayoutPanel, I'm dynamically adding twelve rows (and several columns). When I had the TableLayoutPanel's Rows collection set to Autosize, the 12th row would be generated, but would not display. I changed it to Percentage, with each row getting 8.33% (I actually set it to 8, and it was automatically changed to 8.33).

So that should be perfect to the naked eye (99.99999999%), but now the twelfth row has more space than the others, and the 16th column the same, so the TableLayoutPanel has "dead space" at the bottom and right, and the labels I have in the final row are not aligned with the textBoxes I have in the neighboring column.

In case anybody's interested in seeing the actual code:

```
private void AddControlsToPlatypusTableLayoutPanel()
{
    string lblName;
    string txtbxName;
    int ColNum = 0;
    int RowNum = 0;
    int LoopCounter = 1;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);

    while (LoopCounter <= 96) {
        // Create the Label
        lblName = string.Format("label{0}", LoopCounter);
        var lbl = new Label() {
            Name = lblName,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Margin = new Padding(),
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Text = dt.ToString("HH:mm")
        };
        tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls.Add(lbl, ColNum, RowNum);

        // Create the TextBox
        txtbxName = string.Format("textBox{0}", LoopCounter);
        var txtbx = new TextBox() {
            Name = txtbxName, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Margin = new Padding()
        };
        tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls.Add(txtbx, ColNum + 1, RowNum);

        dt = dt.AddMinutes(15);
        RowNum++;
        LoopCounter++;
        // Move over if at the bottom
        if (RowNum == 12) { 
            ColNum = ColNum + 2;
            RowNum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

By tweaking the Size and Location a smidgin, I can get it all to look good, but now I either have to live with a cushion around it or change the size of the form and all the other controls, or many of them, anyway. So I still consider it a bit irregular that the percentages didn't work out as one would expect them to. I know, I know: WPF. But that's not an option at present.

Comment: What is your Panel's setting for AutoSize, AutoSizeMode, and GrowStyle?

Comment: I'll Czech tomorrow when I'm back at the Platypus factory.

Comment: AutoSize = False
AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly
GrowStyle = AddRows

Now here's something slightly macabre: When I opened the project this a.m., grid lines appear on the TableLayoutPanel; that's fine with me, but why now and not yesterday?

Comment: Changing AutoSize from False to True was a complete, unmitigated disaster of 

the utmost proportions.

Changing AutoSizeMode from GrowOnly to GrowAndShrink made no diff.

Changing GrowStyle from AddRows to FixedSize made no diff.

Changing GrowStyle from AddRows to AddColumns made no diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have set it to 8 then 8*12 conclude to 84% with 16% remaining which will be accommodated in last row as well same case applies to last column. So you need to define it to 100/12 = 8.33%. if you made each row with 8.33% and last row with 8.37% this will look nice. you need to complete 100% in both case of rows or columns. or you can use fix size instead. if you want variable size of table then be sure you do not define size of table and rows height and columns width define table size dynamically.

Comment: As my post says, it was automatically changed to 8.33

Comment: can you post snap of rows to how much it varies,

Comment: I got it to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011893/why-doesnt-my-tablelayoutpanel-use-all-of-its-size-when-divided-by-percentages ( I had to use absolute sizes for the columns rather than percentages*, and increase the width of the label-holding columns to 35 (which leaves only 15 for the textBox-holding columns at a TLP width of 640).)

Comment: Good to hear, that's what I told to be fix size.